# How to perform a Sidekiq callback when a group of workers are complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Lets say I have a Sidekiq task that processes products to my database. Each product is grouped by store, so an overly simplified example of my code would be something like this...

```
stores.each do |store|
  store.products.each do |product|
    ProductWorker.perform_async(product.id)
  end
end
```

When all the products from one store have run. I'd like to update the stores `last_updated` column with the current time. But only when the last task for that store has run. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is exactly what Sidekiq Pro's Batches feature is designed to solve:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches

https://sidekiq.org/products/pro.html

You would write this code:

```
class ProductWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def on_complete(status, params)
    Store.find(params['sid']).update_attribute(:last_updated, Time.now)
  end
  
  def perform(product_id)
    # do something
  end
end


stores.each do |store|
  b = Sidekiq::Batch.new
  b.on(:complete, ProductWorker, 'sid' => store.id)
  b.jobs do
    store.products.find_each do |product|
      ProductWorker.perform_async(product.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Easy.

Comment: Thanks for responding Mike. This is exactly what I was looking for. Keep up the good work!

Comment: How does the callback know when the batch for a specific store is run? What ruby is running behind the scenes?

Comment: is there any other way except pro version to do this?

Answer (score 18):

You can try [`sidekiq-batch`](https://github.com/breamware/sidekiq-batch) gem to solve your problem. It's like paid `Batches` feature of `Sidekiq Pro` and has same api.

Comment: Why has this answer been down voted? It looks like a fairly well written open source alternative including tests.