# Sidekiq. Send Callback after job Done

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq with sidekiq-status to check when the work is done to keep performing the action.
The method I use is not much efficient but it does it.

Controller:

```
  myjob = JobCreator.perform_async(my_param)

  sleep(1)

  10.times do
    status = Sidekiq::Status::get myjob, :job_status
    if ["OK","FAIL","NOMONEY"].include?(status)
      result << status
      break
    end
    sleep(1)
  end
```

How can I make this on a more direct, fast and efficient way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform a Sidekiq callback when a group of workers are complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205339/how-to-perform-a-sidekiq-callback-when-a-group-of-workers-are-complete)

Answer (score 3):

The Pro version of Sidekiq has a [feature called Batches](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches) that also includes the ability to configure [callbacks](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches#callbacks) and fetch the status of a batch.

Batches are defined as a collection of jobs, but nothing prevents you to use a job in a batch.

As far as I know, that's the only feature that currently supports callback.